# Cannot resolve Symbol 'AccessKey'

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Following a tutorial on AWS.  I'm using IntelliJ for the environment. The video is outdated maybe. I need help figuring out why am I getting the error in Terminal

```
  16  public AmazonS3 s3() {
  17     AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
  18              accessKey:"AKIA4OAJ",
  19              secretKey:"UCsI66ZpbJ1F06aCwm"
        );
```

[image]

Comment: All we need is `AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("AKIA4OAJ","UCsI66ZpbJ1F06aCwm")` I am not sure what `accessKey:` and `secretKey:` are? are you simply showing in question for easy understanding?

Comment: I think it was a formatting issue. They all have to be on the same line like the way you wrote it.